# How to create a binary list based on inclusion of list elements in another list

Tags: python, list, boolean, inclusion

Given two lists of words, `dictionary` and `sentence`,
I'm trying to create a binary representation based on the inclusion of words of `dictionary` in the `sentence` such as
`[1,0,0,0,0,0,1,...,0]` where 1 indicates that the ith word in the dictionary shows up in the sentence.

What's the fastest way I can do this?

Example data:

```
dictionary =  ['aardvark', 'apple','eat','I','like','maize','man','to','zebra', 'zed']
sentence = ['I', 'like', 'to', 'eat', 'apples']
result = [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0]
```

Is there something faster than the following considering that I'm working with very large lists of approximately 56'000 elements in size?

```
x = [int(i in sentence) for i in dictionary]
```

Comment: yeah i have over 100,000 sentences each now represented as a list of words that comprise them. I now need to represent each of these sentence as boolean array where a boolean value of 1 at the ith index indicates that the ith word in the dicitionary, which I have previously created, exists in the sentence.

Comment: Using sets you can do this is `O(N)` time complexity, so 10**5 items are not an issue. BTW don't use the word `sentences` here, it's confusing, a `sentence` is a set of space separated words while your sentences list contains simple words.

Comment: Note that the comment of @user2353644 above contradicts with what they initially wrote in the original post which led to some confusion in the answers regarding what should be converted to a set/iterated over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
words = set(['hello','there']) #have the words available as a set
sentance = ['hello','monkey','theres','there']
rep = [ 1 if w in words else 0 for w in sentance ]
>>> 
[1, 0, 0, 1]
```

I would take this approach because sets have O(1) lookup time, that to check if `w` is in `words` takes a constant time. This results in the list comprehension being O(n) as it must visit each word once. I believe this is close to or as efficient as you will get.

You also mentioned creating a 'Boolean' array, this would allow you to simply have the following instead:

```
rep = [ w in words for w in sentance ]
>>> 
[True, False, False, True]
```

Comment: OP is iterating over `words` and searching in `sentences` list, plus the items in your `sentences` list are words not `sentences`.

Comment: No, the OP is iterating over the sentence, and then creating a representation of the sentence based on each word in the sentence either being in a dictionary of words or not. "**where a 1 indicates that the ith word in the dictionary shows up in the sentence.**"

Comment: thanks for you help, I will definitely implements sets. Unfortunately, I will still have to apply this list comp over 100,000 times, as I have 100,000 sentences. I'm trying to see if there is a clever numpy way I can apply something similar to this list comp to a matrix of sentences where each row is a sentence

Comment: I don't believe you can escape from having to visit every word in each sentence.

Comment: @HennyH see OP's sample data, he's iterating over words(dictionary) not sentences.

Answer (score 1):

```
set2 = set(list2)
x = [int(i in set2) for i in list1]
```

Comment: You can't search `"hello"` in `"hello world"` using this.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, My interpretation was that list2 was a list of words from the sentence.

Comment: Your interpretation was quite right, his lists contains simple words not sentences.

Answer (score 0):

use `sets`, total time complexity `O(N)`:

```
>>> sentence = ['I', 'like', 'to', 'eat', 'apples']
>>> dictionary =  ['aardvark', 'apple','eat','I','like','maize','man','to','zebra', 'zed']
>>> s= set(sentence)
>>> [int(word in s) for word in dictionary]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

In case your sentence list contains actual sentences not words then try this:

```
>>> sentences= ["foobar foo", "spam eggs" ,"monty python"]
>>> words=["foo", "oof", "bar", "pyth" ,"spam"]
>>> from itertools import chain

# fetch words from each sentence and create a flattened set of all words
>>> s = set(chain(*(x.split() for x in sentences)))

>>> [int(x in s) for x in words]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```