# 'in' for two sorted lists with the lowest complexity

Tags: python

I have two **sorted** lists, e.g.

```py
a = [1, 4, 7, 8]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I want to know for each item in `a` if it is in `b`. For the above example, I want to find

```py
a_in_b = [True, True, False, False]
```

(or having the indices where `a_in_b` is `True` would be fine too).

Now, both `a` and `b` are very large, so complexity is an issue. If `M = len(a)` and `N = len(b)`. **How can I do this with a complexity lower than `M * O(N)` by making use of the fact that both lists are sorted?**

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe `set.difference()` would be useful? And I think your complexity is `O(n*n)`.

Comment: You can do it by iterating both in lockstep, but really the fastest is the usual "convert the second to a set". Either way is O(n+m). Is there a specific reason why you want to exploit that both are sorted?

Comment: Related: [How to create a binary list based on inclusion of list elements in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16393681/7851470)

Answer (score 6):

You can iterate over your `b` list manually within a loop over `a`. You'll want to advance the `b` iteration when the latest value you've seen from it is less than the current value from `a`.

```
from math import inf

result = []
b_iter = iter(b)                           # create an iterator over b
b_val = -inf
for a_val in a:
    while b_val < a_val:
        b_val = next(b_iter, inf)          # manually iterate on it
    result.append(a_val == b_val)
```

This should have a running time of `O(M+N)`, since each list item gets iterated over at most once (`b` may not even need to be fully iterated).

You could avoid using floating point infinities if you want to, but you'd need to do a bit of extra work to handle some edge cases (e.g. if `b` is empty).

Comment: Thanks!! Do I understand correctly that, depending on the properties of `b`, it might be good to use a binary search (using `bisect`) instead of the manual iteration?

Comment: No binary search is slower (m * log(n)). This algorithm is similar to merging of two sorted lists.

Answer (score 6):

Exploiting sorted'ness is a red-herring for time complexity: The ideal case is to iterate both in lockstep for O(n+m) complexity. This is the same as converting `b` to a set for O(m), then searching the elements of `a` in the set for O(n).

```py
>>> a = [1, 4, 7, 8]
>>> b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> bs = set(b)                 # create set for O(len(b))
>>> [item in bs for item in a]  # check O(len(a)) items "in set of b" for O(1) each
[True, True, False, False]
```

Since most of these operations are builtin, the only costly operation is the iteration over `a` which is needed in all solutions.

However, this will duplicate the references to the items in `b`. If `b` is treated as external to the algorithm, the space complexity is O(m+n) instead of the ideal case O(n) for just the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm having trouble understanding though, not in the last place because the answer seems incomplete. Do you mean by `bs` the result of a binary search?

Comment: @TomdeGeus Ah, sorry. Missed a line. Code edited, you can run it directly now.

Comment: It's not a red herring; the solution which exploits sortedness has the same time complexity, but uses O(1) auxiliary space compared to O(m) auxiliary space for the set-based solution.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but a different approach to the problem using  `set()` uniqueness and [`O(1)` speed of `len()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1115329/797495),  i. e. :

```
a_in_b = []
a = [1,4,7,8]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b_set = set(b) 
for v in a:
    l1 = len(b_set) 
    b_set.add(v) 
    a_in_b.append(l1 == len(b_set))
```

---

Unfortunately, my approach isn't the fastest:

- mistermiyagi: 0.387 ms
- tomerikoo: 0.442 ms
- blckknght: 0.729 ms
- lobito: 1.043 ms
- semisecure: 1.87 ms
- notnotparas: too long
- lucky6qi: too long

[Benchmark](https://trinket.io/python3/749d5dce06)

Comment: So this basically tests whether v was unseen, i.e. not in the b set before being added?

Comment: It tests if the length of the `b_set` is the same after append an element of `a`, if it's the same, then the element already existed (`true`) because a `set` cannot have duplicate values.

Comment: This won't work if there are duplicates in ``a``, does it?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I worked with the example provided, but answering directly to your question, no, it won't work when there's dups in `a`.

Comment: It's still nice to have. Took me a while to wrap my head around. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Use Binary Search here:

```py
def bs(b,aele,start,end):
    if start > end:
        return False
    mid = (start + end) // 2
    if ale == b[mid]:
        return True

    if ale < b[mid]:
        return bs(b, aele, start, mid-1)
    else:
        return bs(b, aele, mid+1, end)
```

For each element in **a** check if it exists in **b** using this method.
Time Complexity: O(m*log(n))

Comment: There's a binary search module in the standard library, so you don't need to write your own. Check out `bisect`. But you can do better in this specific case!

Comment: yes i've used `bisect` before. just thought it would be helpful to mention the code.

Comment: You are not using that a is sorted !

Comment: @hivert using that fact, we can solve this problem by using some modified merge sort algorithm, but I think that would make the time complexity and space complexity O(m+n)

Answer (score 2):

Using sets the order doesn't even matter.

Turn `b` to a set (`O(N)`). Then iterate `a` (`O(M)`), and for each element check if it's in `set_b` (`O(1)`). This will give a time complexity of **`O(max(M, N))`**:

```py
a = [1, 4, 7, 8]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

set_b = set(b)
res = []
for elem in a:
    res.append(elem in set_b)
```

This can of-course be shortened to a nifty list-comp:

```py
res = [elem in set_b for elem in a]
```

Both give:

```
[True, True, False, False]
```

---

For your parenthesized request, simply iterate with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) instead:

```py
for i, elem in enumerate(a):
    if elem in set_b:
        res.append(i)
```

Which will give `[0, 1]`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to keep the order with the `[True, False]` notation. If not then this works really fast.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis This indeed keeps the order of the `True`/`False`...

Comment: Ah, my bad, thought you made `a` a set too!

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is actually `O(M + N)`:

```
a = [1, 1, 4, 7, 8]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c = [0] * len(a) # Or use a dict to stash hits ..

j = 0

for i in range(0, len(a)):
  while j < len(b) - 1 and b[j] < a[i]:
    j += 1
  if b[j] == a[i]:
    c[i] = 1

print(c)
```

For each `i` in `0 ... N` where `N` is length of `a`, only a unique partition / sub-sequence of `b` plus one border number is checked, making it `O(M + N)` all together.

Answer (score 1):

Go through `a` and `b` once:

```
a_in_b = []
bstart = 0
for ai in a:
    print (ai,bstart)
    if bstart == len(b):
        a_in_b.append(False)
    else:
        for bi in b[bstart:]:
            print (ai, bi, bstart)
            if ai == bi:
                a_in_b.append(True)
                break
            elif ai > bi:
                if bstart < len(b):
                    bstart+=1
                if bstart == len(b):
                    a_in_b.append(False)
                continue
```

Comment: The slice operation `b[bstart:]` is `O(N)`, which is going to kill your performance.

Comment: Thanks! Would `b[bstart:] not lead to a lot allocations (`b` being quite large)? Also, here it might be worth to consider a binary search to advance (depending of the properties of `b`) I guess?

Answer (score 1):

You should use binary search algorithm(read about it if you don't know what it is).

The modified `bin_search` function has to return position `right` for which `b[right] >= elem` - the first element in `b` that is greater or equal than searched element from `a`. This position will be used as the left position for next `bin_search` call. Also `bin_search` returns True as a second argument if it have found `elem` in b

```
def bin_search(arr, elem, left):
    right = len(arr)
    while left < right:
        mid = (left+right)//2
        if arr[mid] == elem:
            return (mid, True)
        if arr[mid] < elem:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid
    return (right, False)

def find_a_in_b(a, b):
    new_left = 0
    a_in_b = [False] * len(a)
    
    # we could have used enumerate but size of a is too large
    index = 0
    for i in a:
        new_left, a_in_b[index] = bin_search(b, i, new_left)
        index += 1
    return a_in_b
```

It's probably the best time

P.S. Forget it, i'm stupid and forgot about linear algorithm used in merge sort, so it's not the best

Answer (score 0):

```
for el in a:
    try:
        b = b[b.index(el):]
        a_in_b.append("True")
    except:
        a_in_b.append("False")
```

Comment: Thanks!! Wouldn't the slice keep performance here though?

Comment: `b.index` actually iterates the list so this is `O(M*N)`...

Comment: Not dramatically. Of course, it depends on the size of a list. I woudn't use a hashable object having a scenario like this in my mind: a = [1,2,2,3,4] b=[1,2,2,2,2,2,1000,1001]

Comment: Still, it's iterating the remaining `b` every time and creating new lists each iteration surely takes its toll...

Comment: @Tomerikoo slicing the list avoids the O(M*N), but I see your point!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to convert the lists to a data frame and do an inner merge

The inner join matches like values on a specific column